# How to get nested group controls in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting an error, while i retrieve the nested `formgroup` from the main `formgroup`.

here is the error:

```
Type 'AbstractControl[]' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'AbstractControl[]'
```

my code:

```
 get form(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.patientForm.controls;//works
  }

  formChild(group: string): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    const childControls = (this.patientForm.get(group) as FormArray).controls;
    return childControls; //throws above error. 
  }
```

any one help me to sort this issue? using `get` operator, is it possible to get child group from the main form group?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormArray` contains array of `AbstractControls`.

If you want to get a key map of `AbstractControls` you should expect `FormGroup` returned from the getter:

```
formChild(group: string): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
  const childControls = (this.patientForm.get(group) as FormGroup).controls;
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
  return childControls; //throws above error. 
}
```

Comment: How to validate on `keyup`, because until user delete all values from field i am not getting error. form still valid until he delete all values from field